# React Native: Package firebase has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Given a new project created through the React Native CLI (`npx react-native init ProjectName`), if we install `firebase` and then build on either android or ios, we get a:

```
warn Package firebase has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in /pathToProject/node_modules/firebase/package.json
```

Which will consequently end with the build failing.

I would assume there is some configuration required on the `android` and `ios` folders which is missing, but I can't find any reference around, so not exactly sure what is needed?

I'm on latest versions and so:

```json
"firebase": "^9.1.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.65.1"
```

I already tried deleting the modules and reinstalling as suggested in multiple other places, but that won't help unfortunately.